# typedef of template includes char[][] - works with VS2008 but not gcc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, typedef

I have some library code I'm working with.
It compiles and works under Visual Studio (2008), but not GCC (v4.8.4.)

In a header we have:

```
extern const char menu_styles[MENU_COUNT][MAX_LEN];

typedef SysEnum <s_type_t, c_long, no_style, un_style, MAX_LEN, (char *)&menu_styles> MenuStyleEnum;
```

Where SysEnum is (defined in another file):

```
template<class ETYPE, class BTYPE, int MINV, int MAXV, int MLEN, char* pStr> class SysEnum
```

And gcc borks with the error:

```
error: ‘menu_styles’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Which I completely agree with.  (Furthermore, it's `const char *` cast to `char *`).

I expect VS2008 just compiles this typedef with a `const char *` instead of `menu_styles`, but I'm really not sure.

I'm worried that VisualSudio is adding in some kind of constructor-like code so that this `char *` does indeed point to `menu_styles` whenever this typedef is used.

What can I swap this out with when compiling with GCC?

Comment: Does `extern const char * menu_styles[MENU_COUNT];` work?

Comment: Explain the purpose of the SysEnum template. What does its 6th template parameter expect to accomplish.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik ~ I don't know the purpose of this template.  It seems to hold a bunch of meta-information about a menu style.  template<class ETYPE, class BTYPE, int MINV, int MAXV, int MLEN, char* pStr> class SysEnum [...]

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid that if you don't understand how it's used, there's nothing you can do. This kind of template usage is in violation of the C++ standard. There is no workaround for violating the C++ standard because gcc aims to be a standards-compliant compiler. If you understood what the template is doing, perhaps you could find a different way to do what it's doing, but without knowing what it should do, unfortunately there is no answer.

Comment: @JJ Hakala - No.  GCC says the the "extern" makes it an "invalid type declaration".  Without it, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm answering my own question.

The class passes a static array of strings as an initialiser to the template typedef.  The C++ standard (at the moment) does not allow this.  I guess VS2008 takes this compile-time constant pointer and uses it anyway.  It knows it's not going to change, so it works.

GCC sticks to the standard, refusing.

But in VS2008's defence the GCC version shows a much newer compiler than VS2008.

So to code around the issue, making minimal changes (since it's standard library code purchased at great expense (yes really)), I changed the `char *pStr` to be a simple unsigned integer.  The `pStr` was eventually passed down into further constructors inherited into SysEnum.

I added a type-code to identify the char[][] to be used, and modified the final constructor that took `pStr` as a parameter to accept this code.  Then internal to that constructor it uses that code, such that if it received MENU_STYLES_CODE then it should initialise with the pointer `menu_styles`.  I need to extend this for all the typedefs of this template.

```
typedef SysEnum <s_type_t, c_long, no_style, un_style, MAX_LEN, MENU_STYLES_CODE> MenuStyleEnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to compile

```
extern const char menu_styles[MENU_COUNT][MAX_LEN];

template<const char* pStr> class SysEnum{
  ...
};

typedef SysEnum <???> MenuStyleEnum;
```

I changed the template parameter to `const char*`, because otherwise you have to cast constness away and that is not a Very Good Thing. Basically the question is what `???` should be.

The most common way to define a `char*` template parameter is to have a `char[]` variable somewhere, which would decay to `char*` making everybody happy:

```
extern const char menu_style0[MAX_LEN];
typedef SysEnum <menu_style0> MenuStyleEnum;//compiles...
```

However, as already pointed out in the comments, the standard does not let us do any of the following:

```
typedef SysEnum <menu_styles[0]> MenuStyleEnum;
typedef SysEnum <*menu_styles> MenuStyleEnum;
typedef SysEnum <static_cast<const char *>(&menu_styles)> MenuStyleEnum;
```

I'm not sure a technical limitation is  the reason for this behaviour, after all it is possible to figure out the address of `menu_styles[0]` during the compile time (and the VS does exactly that). My guess would be it does not compile, because the standard says so.

That does not let you a lot of options here. If `SysEnum` uses only the values to which `pStr` is pointing (code like `cout<<pStr`) and the addresses are not important by themselves (which would be the case for code like `pStr==otherCharPointer`), than the following workaround could be a possibility:

```
#define _MENU_STYLE0_ "STYLE0" 
...

extern const char menu_style0[MAX_LEN]= _MENU_STYLE0_;
...

extern const char menu_styles[MENU_COUNT][MAX_LEN]={ _MENU_STYLE0_,  _MENU_STYLE1_, ...};
...

typedef SysEnum <menu_style0> MenuStyleEnum;//compiles!
```

The downside is, that the same information is present in `menu_styleX` and `menu_styles`, which does not feel like a great solution.

If only values from `menu_styles` can be the template parameter, it could be easier to declare:

```
template<size_t Index> class SysEnum{
    //use menu_styles[index] for pStr
};

typedef SysEnum <0> MenuStyleEnum;
```

But than again, you would lose the possibility to use values besides of stored in `menu_styles` and some refactoring in `SysEnum` were needed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but ultimately it suffers from the same problem as the question.  Basically the upshot is that (for very good reasons) this kind of declaration is not valid, and VS2008 should not have allowed it. This section of the library code will need to be re-written for GCC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around understanding the `SysEnum` template a bit. You need to understand how the `menu_styles` parameter is used.

And then you need to patch the library code in a reasonable way, e.g.

```
constexpr const char menu_styles[] = "sample";
template <class ETYPE,
          class BTYPE,
          int MINV,
          int MAXV,
          int MLEN,
          const char* pStr>
class SysEnum;
typedef SysEnum<s_type_t, c_long, no_style, un_style, MAX_LEN, menu_styles>
    MenuStyleEnum;
```